# Write form API values to database

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-6

I want to write Drupal Form value made from API Form, to my database with the following code:
Into my database only appears 1 and nothing more. What's wrong? Thanks!

```
$sql= "INSERT into {test} (id, studiejaar, opleiding, soortStage,
        stageplaats,periodes)VALUES(1, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
db_query($sql, $form['studiejaar']['#value'], $form['opleiding']['#value'], $form['soortStage']['#value'],
            $form['stageplaats']['#value'], $form['periodes']['#value']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, use $form_state['values']['studiejaar'] and so on instead of $form.
- You probably shouldn't specific the id, instead, just leave that away and MySQL will automatically increment the value.
- If you have defined your table with [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_schema/6) (what you need to do!), you could also use [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6).